# ECPG invocation of stored procedure with array arguments in a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to to call a postgres stored function from a ECPG interface that passes char arrays as inputs.
I currently am  getting "too few arguments" when I attempt to open the cursor.
Relevant excerpts:

```
ECPG file:



EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
     const char* cid = connid;
     const char* stmt = NULL;
     char tgrpkey[64];            // group key 
     char ccakey[64];             // call control agent key
     char dhostkey[64];           // dest host key 
     char regusrkey[64];       // Registration user 
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

 stmt = SELECT * FROM  sipbasicquery(:ccakey::char[],:tgrpkey::char,:dhostkey::char[],:regusrkey::char[])";

 EXEC SQL AT :cid PREPARE pstmt FROM :stmt;   
 EXEC SQL AT :cid DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR pstmt;
 EXEC SQL AT :cid OPEN cur;      
 EXEC SQL AT :cid FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO DESCRIPTOR sqlda;
```

---

The stored function exists on my server and  has the following signature.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sipbasicquery(cca character[], tgrp character[],
                                             dhost character[], usr character[])
                      RETURNS SETOF sipbasinfo AS $$
```

Can someone why the too few arguments error is generated?

With ECPG debug enabled the failure looks like:

```
[23064]: prepare_common on line 110: name pstmt; query: "SELECT * FROM sipbasicquery($1::char[],$2::char[],$3::char[],$4::char[])"
[23064]: raising sqlcode -202 on line 117: too few arguments on line 117
```

Arguments  seem to match my stored procedure. Why too few ?
Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use host variables (`:ccakey` etc.) in a query that is itself stored in a host variable (`:stmt`).  Host variables are resolved by the ECPG parser, but that won't work if your query is inside a C string variable.  What is happening now is that the query is sent to the server unaltered, including the `:ccakey::char[]` etc., and that will confuse the backend's parser in random ways.

What you want to use instead is

```
stmt = "SELECT * FROM  sipbasicquery(?::char[], ?::char, ?::char[], ?::char[])";
```

(The casts might not be necessary.  YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, That was part of my problem. Another issue was the when the cursor is actually opened it has to use the "USING" clause which then references the HOST variables. This is progress though I am now left with an error. "array must start with "{" or dimension. That is perhaps another topic thread if I can't figure it out today.